# getting information about which push pin was clicked

Tags: c#, geolocation, maps, windows-phone-8.1

I'm building a windows phone 8.1 app that reads a file ( which holds GPS points, each point consists of e.g. latitude and longitude fields). For each point I have it so it's displayed with a little pushpin icon on the map control, based on its coordinated from the above file. I want to have the pushpins clickable and the ultimate goal is to obtain Latitude and longitude of the point the user clicked and do appropriate action based on which one is clicked. How can I get hold of this information ? This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
 private async void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = sender as Geopoint;

        MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("point tapped: " + point.Position.Latitude );

        await msgbox.ShowAsync();
    }
```

That's my template:

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="myMap">
        <Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }">
            <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="Assets/pushpin.png" Tapped="Image_Tapped" Width="50" Height="50"  Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding}"></Image>                     
                </DataTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl>
     </Maps:MapControl>
```

This is what I use to read the file and display pushpins (it shows them fine)

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Geoposition position = await App.DataModel.GetCurrentPosition();

        await myMap.TrySetViewAsync(position.Coordinate.Point, 16D);

        List<Geopoint> list = new List<Geopoint>();            

        bool exist; // used to check if JSON file exists

        exist = await App.DataModel.FileExistsAsync();

        if (exist == true)
        {
            // read the file and load points into a list
            await App.DataModel.ReadFile();


            foreach (var point in App.DataModel.notes)
            {
                Geopoint geo = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
                {
                    Latitude = point.Latitude,
                    Longitude = point.Longitude
                });

                list.Add(geo);
            }
        }

        myMap.DataContext = list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Image_Tapped` handler, the sender variable is not a `Geopoint`, it is an `Image`. But the `Geopoint` should be the `DataContext` of this Image

```
var point = (sender as Image).DataContext as Geopoint;
```